# WHM/Cpanel SSL Certificate on Mail Server

Tags: ssl, cpanel, whm

I need to have SSL on a client website mail server, so https://mail.domain.com for example.  I purchased a certificate for the primary domain and cPanel does allow for this to cover all subdomains, but the certificate itself is limited to just the primary domain.

I would prefer not to have to purchase an expensive wildcard SSL, is there a way to put a second SSL certificate on just mail.domain.com?  cPanel does not have the mail subdomain as a possibility in the dropdown for SSl certificates.

I assume maybe I would have to create a subdomain or something...not sure if anyone else has done this.

Comment: Try using LetsEncrypt

Comment: I have tried that also, but since apple ios 11 it is no longer showing as trusted on apple devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in this case you should regenerate the CSR certificate and re-issue the SSL. Most of the SSL certificates, even the cheapest ones allow you to use the SSL for the main domain + 1 subdomain, in your case mail. So go to cPanel, regenerate your CSR certificate and in the hosts field add domain.tld + mail.domain.tld on the next line. Then with the new CSR, go to your SSL provider and try to issue a new SSL certificate using your new CSR. Then the new generated SSL should cover your domain + mail.domain. And you should be all set. Even the really cheap SSL certificates from SSL2Buy can be used for domain + 1 subdomain (and they are about 9$/year for a COMODO simple SSL certificate). So give it a try

Answer (score 0):

If you are using shared account they will offer you free ssl certificate which you can generate from Cpanel and if you are using wordpress framework for your website you can install ssl plugin there and can activate ssl on your website.